# How to lstinput a text file path and get content of ext file into pdf

Tags: listings

I tried to insert some data using listings package labels(lstset) into pdf which was successful but if the same data is put into a text file ans lstinput it as follows is not successful .Can some one please make the following non-working example work.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,breaklines=true}
\lstset{framextopmargin=50pt,frame=bottomline}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}

\lstinputlisting{C:/Temp/test.txt}


\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

---

OUTPUT:

\lstinputlisting{C:/Temp/test.txt}

---

Also the contents in test.txt IS AS FOLLOWS

## include

main()
{

print "HELLO";
}

Comment: You should make the example be an _example of the problem_ not an example that works. If you are getting `\lstinputlisting{C:/Temp/test.txt}` in the output you must have put that command in the wrong place, where it is being read as text not as a command, such as inside a listings or verbatim. But you leave us to guess...

Comment: `\lstinputlisting{C:/Temp/test.txt}` should not be inside a `lstlisting` environment: it replace the whole thing.

Comment: I have now edited the post and put the non-working code in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\lstinputlisting` instruction *replaces* a `lstlisting` environment. With your input, you are asking *not* to interpret `\lstinputlisting`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,breaklines=true}
\lstset{framextopmargin=50pt,frame=bottomline}


\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting{C:/Temp/test.txt}

\end{document}
```